# Qtip it does not work the first time click, next click all OK

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, qtip2

I'm using the jQuery qtip plugin. I want the content of the qtip to be an php code, loaded dynamically. Here my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mapa').qtip({
         show: 'click',
         hide: 'click',
         content:{
                    text: function(event, api) {
                             $.ajax({
                                   url: '/google_maps/mapa.php'
                                   })
                            .then(function(content) {
                               api.elements.tooltip.html(content);
                            }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                               api.set('content.text', status + ':  ' + error);
                            });
                            return 'Loading...'; // Set some initial text

                    },
                },
        position: {
        my: 'top right',
        at: 'top center',
        },
        style: {
        classes: 'qtip-blue',
        }
    });
});
```

Then I select a link with the id="mapa" to load Qtip with php code the fisrt click no load php code in Qtip, the second and next click, Qtip work OK. If i refresh page, again no work first, second all OK.
Can anyone help me? Error committing in my call on ajax? Or elsewhere? 
Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you try changing `api.elements.tooltip.html(content);` to `api.set('content.text', content);`, does it show your content on the first click?

Comment: if i changing to `api.set('content.text', content);` the first click no work and also no work second :( In the second and next click no work the Qtip